# Regex to find a string that may contain a single string word

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex that matches for a specific string as long as it does not contain a single string word.

Below, I want to return "I think one is cool" but not "one" because I only want it as long as it's not by itself.

Ex.
one
I think one is cool  <--- I want this "one"

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: can't understand your example.

Comment: We need more info. What's your input, your regular expression and your expect output.

Comment: You want to match all lines that contain one word only?

Comment: I think they want to match lines containing a specific word, but also more.

Comment: Also the language you're doing this in. While the common forms of regexes are pretty similar, they aren't exactly the same.

Comment: Hi, Scott. If my answer worked for you, can you please mark it as the answer with the green checkmark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to match lines containing your word, but not consisting of only your word.

Depending on your programming language there might be better ways to do this, but you can search for the regex `/(\w+\sone|one\s\w+)/` to find lines containing something like a word, then a space, then `"one"`, *or* `"one"`, a space, and then something like a word. So this would match every line here:

```
one two three
this is one line
the number one
```

but no line here:

```
one
lonely
something else
```

If you want it to match something like `"lonely"`, remove whitespace escape sequences (`\s`). If you want to match not only word-characters before and/or after, replace the `\w` with a dot `.`.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. So basically I wanted to capture the "one" when it's part of a string only, not when it's by itself or when the string does not contain the word at all like "something else" or "lonely". I am trying to match unbranded keywords with "one" being the branded keyword that I don't want to capture. So if it's not "one" by itself then it should be captured in the regex as an unbranded keyword.

Answer (score 2):

For regex, the beginning of a string will be typically signified with **^** (carat) and end with **$** (US Dollar sign)

Many flavors of regex allow you to do forward/backward lookarounds, so basically you want to find the word one that is not by itself, but part of a string.

You're looking for the word **one**, so you can use **\b** around the word, which is usually syntax for a word boundary. This helps you filter out searches like n**one**.

So here is the regex that would work for you:

```
(?<!^)\bone\b(?!$)
```

This means that out of the following strings, only the bolded text will be a match:

> one
>
> is the **one**
>
> **one** for all
>
> i can none of

Comment: Right, a much better solution than my answer.